# Chrome dev tools protocol. Message Emulate.setUserAgentOverride

Tags: php, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to substitute user agent via message [`Emulation.setUserAgentOverride`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/#method-setUserAgentOverride).

I send the message with parameters:

```
[userAgentOverride] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36
[acceptLanguage] => ru-RU
[platform] => Windows
```

And I got strange error, which I can't resolve:

```
[code] => -32602
[message] => Invalid parameters
[data] => Failed to deserialize params.userAgent - BINDINGS: mandatory field missing at position 175
```

The weirdness is, that user agent string length in this case is 110. And I'm stuck what does it mean. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just mistook the name of parameter:
"userAgentOverride" has to be "userAgent".